# How do I display the products and nodes of the same author in the current page?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, users, commerce

I wish to display a block with the products of the same author as the current page.

Contextual filters work on node pages, but not on product pages.

In contextual filters, I add "Product: Author" but no options are available for products.

There is no check box for products, as for content "Also look for a node and use the author of the node".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you, but that's not my question.

"User 1" created:

- product 1, product 2, product 3.
- node 1, node 2, node 3.

"User 2" created:

- product 4, product 5, product 6.
- node 4, node 5, node 6.

When I visit node 5, I have the products and nodes of the same author in a block in the second sidebar:

- product 4, product 5, product 6.
- node 4, node 6.

When I visit product 3, nothing is displayed. Because the contextual filter does not find the author in the product page.

Normally it should display the products and nodes of the same author in a block in the second sidebar:

- product 1, product 2.
- node 1, node 2, node 3.

Comment: The answer to my question is here : https://www.drupal.org/node/2904908#comment-12236586

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the relations and contextual filters.

You need to add a relation to the Author and then another relation to Product using the Author as a relationship, then go to add a Contextual filter Content ID (Provide default value [Content ID from URL]) and use Product as Relationship.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it does not work because there is no relationship to the product in a node view

Comment: @ZenImagine I can't get the point, you don't have which relation? If you have an Author and a Product you have a relation.

Comment: When I am on a product, I want to see in a block the nodes of the same author. I followed your answer but it does not work.

Comment: @ZenImagine well this works for me, the first relation is with the product author.

Comment: I updated my question